# How to get line from a file using line number and edit it easily?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, editor

I want to know how one can get the extracted content from a file using line number. I have crores of lines in the file and sometimes while importing it in some database, like mongodb, it gives trouble. So I need to edit it. But opening GB's of file again and again just to edit a single line is not worthy.
Hence, I would like to know how I can extract the content from a file using its line number and then edit anything, that I want to edit and save it to the file again, without opening the file completely. 
Say for examples:

```
command line_number 20000 /path/to/input/file
```

output:

```
This your first testing text.
edit line_number 20000 /path/to/input/file
```

Then the line appear and I move to specific characters, say `your` in the line and change it to `my`.  Now my new content on the line becomes:

```
This is my first testing text.
```

Please note that I do not know whether the line has the word or not. So, first I need to check the line. Display the line using line number. and then edit it.
Is there a way to achieve it.
Let me clear everyone, I am using UBUNTU 16.04. This question is completely UBUNTU based and no other OS or Linux distribution. Please not this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sed` or `perl` to print line X:

```
$ cat -n input.txt                                                                                    
     1  roses are red
     2  violets are blue
     3  sed is interesting
     4  and perl is too

$ perl -ne 'print $_ if $. == 3'  input.txt                                                           
sed is interesting
$ sed -n '3p' input.txt                                                                               
sed is interesting
```

Then you can use `sed 'NUMBERs/WORD/NEWWORD/' file.txt`

```
$ sed '3s/interesting/fun/'  input.txt                                                                
roses are red
violets are blue
sed is fun
and perl is too
```

You can use `-i` flag as well to edit file in-place.

Same with Perl:

```
$ perl -pe 's/interesting/fun/ if $. == 3'  input.txt                                                 
roses are red
violets are blue
sed is fun
and perl is too
```

**NOTE**:  With the two editing examples, you don't need to know whether the line contains word or not. Both `perl` and `sed` will replace the word if and only if the line contains the word/pattern. If it doesn't - the line will remain the same.

Comment: I do not know what is there on the line. In question I just gave an example. I need to first display the line to see what is there. How can I find a word if I don't know whether the line contain it or not?

Comment: @JafferWilson  OK. I'll edit my answer. Your original question wasn't very clear.

Comment: I have edited the question you can check now.

Comment: Are you searching for a particular word, or are you checking and maybe modifying whatever is in a particular line [number]? Or some kind of combination of particular words and line numbers?

Comment: @sudodus It is simple. I am looking for the error in the line. While inserting in database like mongodb if any error occurs then it will show you the line number and the error. I want to see that line with line number. And if there is any error in that line I want to edit that particular line. May be replacing few characters or word is what required many a times. Hence, to know the proper error I need to know the line and check it. Then only I can make edit, right?

Comment: I think Serg's answer provides the tools for you to view the line and to edit it. Even two sets of tools: command lines using sed or perl :-)

Comment: @sudodus Yeah I think so. but this is not editing the same file. It is just showing and while editing generating the total different file as result. But I appreciate the thought.

Comment: Is this addressing your issue: `sed` will write to standard output and you can redirect to a file. `sed -i` will write to the same file name '--in-place'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53374/discussion-between-sudodus-and-jaffer-wilson).

Answer (score 0):

You can use vi command to edit files without opening them:

```
vi -c "%s/<old_value>/<new_value>/g|wq" <file_path>
```

for example

```
vi -c "%s/<100>/<200>/g|wq" /home/aditya/sample.txt
```

Update 1:

```
sed '<line_number>!d' <filepath> ( this will print the line)


sed -i '<line_number>s/.*/<new_text>/' <filepath>  ( this is replace everthing in line with 'new_text')
```

Update 2 :

```
sed -i '<line_number>s/<old_text>/<new_text>/' <filepath>  ( this is replace 'old_text' with 'new_text')
```

See if this helps.

Comment: I do not use vim. I do not know how to interact with it. Can you show some commandline method for such task?

Comment: that is the terminal command I gave you. :P 
you have to put that command in terminal,  it internally calls 'vi' and do the find & replace for you.
if the old_value is found, it will be replaced by new_value. :)

Comment: How can I know what  is therein the line? First I should know the line then only I can edit it. I have only line number to see the line. Blindly I cannot put any value. What do you think? :)

Comment: well, that's a tough requirement you have got there :P 
I will update answer after checking out few things.

Comment: Sure.. I know it is a bit tough. Trying from one week to get out of it. At last have posted the question here to know.